# Get-inboxrule -mailbox jdoe | disable-inboxrule -confirm:$false >>>> not working.

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

I have a powershell script that disable user's AD accounts. One part is to disable the exchange inbox rules.

However when I try to run this.

```
 Get-inboxrule -mailbox jdoe | disable-inboxrule -confirm:$false
```

I get this confirm popup.

Using Outlook Web App or Windows powershell to modify your rules will delete any rules what were previously turned off using outlook. If you want to preserve the rules you turned off using Outlook, select No and user outlook to edit your rules, are you sure you want to proceed?

How can I stop the confirm prompt?

Answer (score 0):

think this did it.

```
Get-inboxrule -mailbox jdoe | disable-inboxrule -confirm:$false -AlwaysDeleteOutlookRulesBlob
```